# Fixed-increment adjustment of constant-current source

Tags: potentiometer, lm317

I am using the LM317 as a constant-current source according to Figure 22 on the ON-Semi datasheet [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm317-d.pdf).

[image]

I would like to control the current in fixed increments rather than the continuous provided by a pot, however I am unsure how to go about it.

For fixed-increment voltage regulation, you could just have a multi-select switch/knob and have different resistors connected to each pin as Voltage Adjust is a variable resistor. But because Current Limit Adjust is a potentiometer, this doesn't work. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a few points, and are happy with a rotary switch, you could replace the two resistors in the feedback divider with a chain of resistors, then use the switch to tap the desired ratio.

For failsafe behaviour during switching of a voltage regulator, it is normally better to use the switch to short out one of more resistors (rather than just swapping tap points) because that always leaves a well defined minimum feedback path.

In the case of the potentiometer used in the current limit circuit, using the resistor chain suggested above with a make before break switch would probably suffice.

More generally, for full computerized control, you can use a DAC to inject an additional current into the feedback pin of the regulator.  This then adds an additional variable control term into the feedback equation.

The specifics are covered in a number of other answers, with this one [Adjusting buck regulator with DAC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498222/adjusting-buck-regulator-with-dac) being one of the best.

[image]

(The answer and above circuit is actually for an adjustable voltage regulator, but as you already know, this is easy to convert into an adjustable current source.)

You could also consider using a digitally controlled potentiometer (pure silicon, not motorized physical), but you will need to look carefully at the control loop bandwidth and voltage ranges.

Comment: This makes sense, I think I will go for the rotary switch for simplicity's sake, and I don't really feel like going into digital land. Just one question: What is the configuration for shorting out resistors in your second point?

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully clear this up.  You have a chain of resistors (like a pot track),with each step connected to one of the rotary switch contacts, and the common contact taking the role of the pot wiper.  As with the "Adjust 2" Voltage Adjust in Fig 22, this means even if the wiper goes open circuit there is still a well defined feedback path.  In the setup for current control, if you need well defined behaviour during switching, the easiest approach is to use a make-before-break rotary switch.